# Why does my transparent icon have a square shadow on the desktop?

Tags: svg, transparency, icon

I'm trying to make an icon with transparent background. The icon has the shape of a circle, but when I put the icon on my desktop, there is a square shadow around it as though it were a solid icon. Other icons with transparent backgrounds don't seem to have this problem:

[image: icon example]

I made the icon out of an svg which I edited together from different svg files in Inkscape and tried making icons out of it with different tools, such as online converters like convert.io, and also with gimp. (I also tried with paint.net and a batch file for inkscape but paint.net made the icon very pixellated and the batch file did not work for me and I don't know enough about inkscape to be able to correct it.)

At first I thought the problem was that the original shapes of the svg extended past the circle and I used Inkscape's "clip" function to crop away the rest, but then I released the clip and cropped the paths to not extend past the circle and the end result was still the same.

Comment: If the box is *not* present in the SVG.. then it *must* be how your OS is rendering the icon on your desktop, *not* the artwork.

Comment: I think it's possibly a Windows bug. I'm not entirely sure what starts the problem off. For me, restarting the computer deleting the icons from the desktop, creating them in another folder (not the desktop), then copy pasting on the desktop seems to resolve the issue. Saving an ico file from an application such as GIMP directly to the desktop also seems to set it off, even affecting icon files that were previously displaying OK on the desktop. It's a weird bug.

Comment: It might have something to do with the size and format.

Comment: @BillyKerr I did not create the icon on the desktop, I just created a shortcut to the original icon on the desktop. I tried copying them but it did not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Can this be migrated to SuperUser?